# Sum of 2 different twig variables

Tags: php, twig

I have 2 twig variable:

One is in $

The second is a double

`{{ var1 + var2 }}` is giving an error:

eg.

```
var1 = $5.00

var2 = 10.00
```

Comment: remove `$` from the first variable before adding them.

Comment: This won´t work since var1 includes a dollar sign. remove it and it should be working.

Comment: Stop passing a combination of formatted and unformatted variables to your template. Decide which layer is responsible for calculation and which for presentation, and do the work in the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding a float `var2` on to a string `var1`. You can remove the dollar sign from `var1` like such.

```
{% set var1 = var1|replace({ '$': '' }) %}
{{ var1 + var2 }}
```

You may also need to target `&dollar;` as well as $

```
{% set var1 = var1|replace({'$': '', '&dollar;': ''}) %}
```

Edit: As suggested in comments of your original question by @iainn, you should attempt to make this uniform rather than a mixture of non-formatted and formatted values.